# Why are there scant mentions of Moshiach in the Mishnah?

Tags: messiah, mishna

The corpus of the Mishnah includes only 2 references to Moshiach (Brachot 1:5, Sotah 9:15) and both of which seem to be in passing. I'm curious to know if any commentaries explain why mentions or discussion of Moshiach are infrequen/lacking in the Mishnah, even in places (like Avot 5:20 or the beraita of R' Pinchas ben Yair at the end of Sotah ibid) where one might expect to find such references.

Comment: Generally Mishnah is concise and the gemera is more expansive discussion

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would one expect that a law code like the Mishnah would have any discussion of messianic times? It is perhaps more surprising that there are even any references at all.